# Substrate from the cursor position

Tags: jquery

I apologize for English in advance. I can not do one thing.
There are 9 squares measuring 370-370. When you move the cursor to any of the squares on the far side of the square, the cursor should appear with a translucent square and enter the square on which the cursor is pointing. But it does not always work for me. Help me please.If you need HTML OR CSS just ask. Thank you. Here's how I do:

```
enter code here $(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 370, limitY = 370;

 $(".cities-featured-item").mouseenter(function (e) {

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
      mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
      mouseScrollX = e.pageX;
     if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
     if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
      //console.log('ENTER ' + mouseX + ' - '+ mouseY);
      //alert(e.pageX+" - "+e.pageY);

     if (mouseY < 25) {
         $(this).children("div.layout").css({left: 0, top: "-100%", transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)", transition: "all 200ms easy"});
         $(this).children("div.layout").animate({top: 0}, 200);
     }
     if (mouseX < 25) {
         $(this).children("div.layout").css({top: 0, left: "-100%", transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)", transition: "all 200ms easy"});
         $(this).children("div.layout").animate({left: 0}, 200);
     }
      if (mouseX > 350) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({top: 0, left: "100%", transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)", transition: "all 200ms easy"});
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({left: 0}, 200);
      }
      if (mouseY > 350) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({left: 0, top: "100%", transform: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)", transition: "all 200ms easy"});
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({top: 0}, 200);
      }

      //$(this).children("img.pricel").animate({top: "135px", left: "135px"}, 200);
      //$(this).children("img.pricel").animate({left: "+=135px"}, 500);
     // $(this).children(".cities-featured-item-content").html(mouseX+" - "+mouseY);

  });
  $(".cities-featured-item").mouseleave(function (e) {

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
      mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);

      //console.log('LEAVE ' + mouseX + ' - '+ mouseY);
      //alert(e.pageX+" - "+e.pageY);
      if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
      if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
      if (mouseY < 25) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({top:"-100%"}, 200);
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({left: 0, transform: "matrix(0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0)" , transition: "all 200ms easy"});
      }
      if(mouseX < 25) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({left: "-100%"}, 200);
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({top: 0, transform: "matrix(0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0)" , transition: "all 200ms easy"});
      }
      if(mouseX > 350) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({left: "100%"}, 200);
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({top: 0, transform: "matrix(0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0)" , transition: "all 200ms easy"});
      }
      if(mouseY > 350) {
          $(this).children("div.layout").animate({top: "100%"}, 200);
          $(this).children("div.layout").css({left: 0, transform: "matrix(0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0)" , transition: "all 200ms easy"});
      }
      //$(this).children("img.pricel").animate({top: mouseY +'px' , left: mouseX + 'px'}, 200);
      //$(this).children("img.pricel").animate({left: "-=235px"}, 500);
      //$(this).children(".cities-featured-item-content").html(mouseX+" - "+mouseY);


  });
```

Comment: The question says 'not always' but you should provide a reproducible case. Also, please ask a specific question.

Comment: then what I need to do on the site: http: //test.citycard.travel/en/ ... this I did. But the script works with errors. If possible go see

Comment: If I quickly move the cursor around squares, I have errors